# Errors with JQuery UI hosted on Google

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Get this error with Google hosted JQuery UI. Seems Google hosted JQuery loads OK though.

Datepicker controls are not working. This occurs to several users from one customer only. Other customers not reporting any issues and I can't replicate the error on my end.

Any ideas? Thanks

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zune 4.7)

Timestamp: Thu, 28 Mar 2013 02:43:32 UTC

Message: Expected '}'

Line: 5

Char: 64890

Code: 0

URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Nope, tried to run it in the console manually and it runs fine.

Comment: Try clearing your cache?

Comment: This is only happening to a single customer with multiple users from New Zealand.

Comment: is there some dynamic insertion happening based on location?

Comment: @Limelights No. We have other clients in NZ not reporting problems. We've tested the site from within NZ using website testing site and no probs. Could it be a caching thing. We have put through an update over the previous weekend, maybe coincidence only. But we now use .noconflict. But like I said, it works for us, and it works on IE8 testing on browserstack.

Comment: One other thing which may be relevant, if  a user forces a refresh the arrows show, which means the calendar images have loaded and presumably the datepicker gets loaded ok. This may sometimes take a couple of refreshes. Also, this problem has been reported by several users so is not isolated to a single user.

Comment: Problem was solved by clearing the cache to Google hosted JQuery //ajax.googleapis.com. Thanks to @BurningtheCodeigniter for suggestion.